# moving a image without selecting the buttons - C#

Tags: c#, events, button, key

I want to create a game (Multicolor maze), involves using a image ove using arrow keys, but during runtime, the buttons are selected and not the image when arrow keys are pressed?

[Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e38Uy.png)

[UPDATED]

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
            System.Console.WriteLine("here"); 
        }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // for the image move 
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(HeartSprite.Location.X);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(HeartSprite.Location.Y);

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x = x += 25;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 25;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 25;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 25;

        HeartSprite.Location = new Point(x, y);

        e.Handled = true;

    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Does anything move with the arrow keys?

Comment: The heart image expected to be move by arrow keys , but during the run, i just selecting the buttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `e.Handled = true;` at the end of the function to block the buttons stealing the input

Your code becomes:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // for the image move 
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(HeartSprite.Location.X);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(HeartSprite.Location.Y);

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 25;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 25;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 25;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 25;

        HeartSprite.Location = new Point(x, y);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still no effect... Sorry :(

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Try adding System.Console.WriteLine("here"); somewhere in your KeyDown handler to see if it is even working.

Comment: It's a window form, not a console

Comment: Yes, visual studio however will give you an output log when debugging the application.

Comment: Yes I debugging it